# VSCode Java intellisense wont work for plugin vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I installed `vscjava.vscode-java-pack` extension and out of the box the intellisense did not work.

I'm trying to use Java intellisense (error and code completion) on VSCode. I installed `openjdk-11-jdk` on my debian10. Intellisense wont work.

I then tried adding:

```
"java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"
```

on settings.json and it also did not change anything. No errors showed and no code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Code completion in Visual Studio Code for Java is provided by [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java).

In addition, there's also AI-assisted IntelliSense called [IntelliCode](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/services/intellicode/), which can be found in extension marketplace. It saves you time by putting what you're most likely to use at the top of your completion list.

For java development in VS Code, It's recommended to install [**Java Extension Pack**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_installing-extensions). Please reinstall the required extension and try again.